How to extract columns from CSV file, process and create a CSV file based on the extract and processing result?
The is a snipped from the source CSV file.
%status,date,job,project,start,end,description
%
//,18.03.2021,sib,sib-dede,07:00,15:00,dede-mongo
%
//,11.06.2021,sib,sib-dede,07:00,15:00,dede-mongo
%
//,24.06.2021,sib,sib-dede,07:00,15:00,dede-mongo
%
?,02.08.2021,sib,sib-accounting,14:35,16:35,business-plan
%
?,13.10.2021,sb,sb-accounting,11:30,12:00,e-mail-pump

I like to extract from the source CSV file the start time in column 5 and the end time in column 6.
Next, based on start and end time I like to process the duration in hours or minutes (don't mind).
Eventually, I like to grab the source CSV file, insert a new column between the existing column 6 and 7 with the processed duration and save this addition in a result CSV file.
Done anyone has an idea how to face this challenge on a GNU Debian Linux command line?
I am aware that I can cut specific columns from a CSV file like this.
cut -d, -f5,6 < ./source.csv > ./result.csv

However, I am still missing the duration processing and the result CVS file creation.
PS: I have a preference for Bash.
PPS: There are related questions like this but I found none close to this question.

There are really those strange % lines inbetween?

Yes, those strange % lines are indeed inbtween.

I removed the strange % lines like this.

please update the question with the expected output

I suspect those "weird lines" are actually a representation of some control character in your %status column that something else you're doing is making look like lines with just % followed by lines starting with % or // when it's really just a %<control char>// or similar string at the start of each line. You should really figure that out to get a robust solution that can just handle those fields properly as-is.


I have a preference for Bash

But you could do all of it in one go, e.g. using mktime from GNU Awk (assuming the % signs (or the subsequent newlines) in your sample are just a typo, and that the time in column 6 is higher than the one in column 5, otherwise the result is negative):
awk -F , -v OFS=, '{
  $8=$7; $7=(
    mktime(sprintf("0 0 0 %d %d 0", substr($6,1,2), substr($6,4,2))) - 
    mktime(sprintf("0 0 0 %d %d 0", substr($5,1,2), substr($5,4,2)))
  ) / 60; print
}' source.csv


Cheers! I removed the strange % lines like this. However, the duration calculation is not complete yet. For sub hour durations this answer rounds to the next full hour up or down.

First, I thought I have to substitute substr($6,3,2) with substr($6,3,4) and so on, but it turns out this is not enough.

Now I got it! You need to substitude substr($6,3,2) with substr($6,4,2) and substr($5,3,2) with substr($5,4,2). Do you mind adjusting your answer so that I can mark it as solution?

@dancesWithCycles Yes, sorry for the typo, thanks for spotting! substr("14:35",3,2) would produce :3, but we need substr("14:35",4,2) to get 35.

Assuming that:

The timestamps are all the same day since you don't have any indication of date in your input and so no robust way to handle durations that could be longer than 24 hours,
The timestamps represent standard time and so there is no possible hour change for daylight savings time consideration required,
You really do have lines of just % followed by lines starting with // or ? in your input, and
You also want the header line modified to include a title such as diff for the column you're adding

then using any awk:
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    NF > 1 {
        if ( NR == 1 ) {
            diff = "diff"
        }
        else {
            split($5, b, ":")
            split($6, e, ":")
            beg = b[1]*60 + b[2]
            end = e[1]*60 + e[2]
            diff = end - beg
        }
        $6 = $6 OFS diff
        print
    }
' file
%status,date,job,project,start,end,diff,description
//,18.03.2021,sib,sib-dede,07:00,15:00,480,dede-mongo
//,11.06.2021,sib,sib-dede,07:00,15:00,480,dede-mongo
//,24.06.2021,sib,sib-dede,07:00,15:00,480,dede-mongo
?,02.08.2021,sib,sib-accounting,14:35,16:35,120,business-plan
?,13.10.2021,sb,sb-accounting,11:30,12:00,30,e-mail-pump

No need to run grep first - piping grep to awk is an antipatterm, see https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award#grep.
